# Task.WaitAll remain blocked when task Fault execution

Tags: c#, .net

I have tasks created in this way:

```
public static Task<T> RunAsync<T>(Func<T> function, CancellationToken token) {
     if (function == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("");
     var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => {
        try {
           T result = function();
           tcs.SetResult(result);
        }
        catch (Exception exc) { tcs.TrySetException(exc); }
     }, token);
     return tcs.Task;
  }
```

I add task in list after this method.
In System.Timer event i check the execution of tasks to enable/disable buttons like this:

```
 if (this.Tasks.Count > 0) {
        Task.WaitAll(this.Tasks.ToArray(), this.cancToken);
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => EnableControls()));
        this.Task.Clear();
     }
```

Well, if tasks finish correctly all works fine but if tasks generate exception by cancellationToken and status changes in "Fault" the WaitAll remains blocked.. Why? I cannot understand.

I have raise cancellation in my Task function like this:

```
   if (cancToken.IsCancellationRequested)
     this.cancToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the point of `RunAsync`? It does the same what a regular `Task` already does by default -- executes a delegate on the thread pool.

Comment: @Yarik Did you mean "what a regular `Task.Run`" does? `Task` by itself **not** queue tasks on the thread pool

Comment: `Task.Run`, `Task.Factory.StartNew`, or `new Task(...).Start()`, whatever. Unless you specify `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`, it will use the thread pool.

Comment: You should read more about `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`. Don't be confused by the word "queue" there, it will run your delegates in parallel depending on the number of threads in the thread pool (which is usually equal to the number of the CPU cores).

Comment: That's not a regular task, that's a CPU-bound task. IO-bound Tasks do not run on a thread pool thread nor they should. (You are right that `RunAsync` is useless though)

Comment: Where's your CancellationTokenSource? It seems to me that `if (cancToken.IsCancellationRequested) this.cancToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` will do nothing at all. It certainly won't trigger cancellation.

Comment: I think you are missing a `cancToken.Cancel();` somewhere

Comment: Hi spender, when i cancel task all works fine and execution code go in "tcs.TrySetException(exc)" this mean that token is correct called. The problem is after TrySetException, WaitAll don't see that task is in fault mode in my opinion.

Comment: Hi Camilo, i call cancel in button click.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto We're not talking about I/O-bound tasks.

Comment: `Task.WaitAll` will throw exception if any task has faulted - I don't see you handle it in provided code.

Comment: @TheOverrider Answering your original question, in order to make it work as you expect, you should set your `TaskCompletionSource` to cancelled by calling `SetCanceled` once the `CancellationToken` is cancelled, but, as I already said, I don't see any point in `RunAsync`.

Comment: @Yarik You said "regular task", you didn't say CPU-bound tasks. So your comment makes no sense

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto An I/O bound task does not do anything, you cannot "run" it, because it is an abstraction over a certain I/O operation that has already started. That's why when I say "does by default", I mean a CPU-bound task.

Comment: @Yarik, why called RunAsync? Task, like your previous comment, already started.